# Add kerberos from pypi to Anaconda under Windows

Tags: windows, kerberos, anaconda, pypi, conda

Complete noob so would appreciate a step-by-step solution.

I would like to add [kerberos](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kerberos) package to Anaconda but don't know how to do it.

I have tried the using conda command line: `pip install kerberos` but it failed.

Does anyone know how to go about it?

This is the error log from pip:

```
C:\Users\woodas\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Scripts\gcc.bat -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Users\woodas\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\include -IC:\Users\woodas\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\PC -c src/kerberos.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\kerberos.o '{' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.    
    gcc.exe: error: '{': No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: is: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: not: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: recognized: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: as: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: an: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: internal: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: or: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: external: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: command,: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: operable: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: program: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: or: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: batch: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: file.: No such file or directory
    error: command   'C:\\Users\\woodas\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1  
    Complete output from command   C:\Users\woodas\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\woodas\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_woodas\\kerberos\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\woodas\appdata\local\temp\pip-guybp4-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:  
    running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'kerberos' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src
C:\Users\woodas\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Scripts\gcc.bat -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Users\woodas\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\include -IC:\Users\woodas\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\PC -c src/kerberos.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\kerberos.o '{' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
gcc.exe: error: '{': No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: is: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: not: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: recognized: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: as: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: an: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: internal: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: or: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: external: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: command,: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: operable: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: program: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: or: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: batch: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: file.: No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Users\\woodas\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Can you give us the error message from when `pip install` failed it would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Try running `conda remove libpython` and running pip install again.

Comment: @asmeurer it didn't help unfortunately

Comment: I think there is an issue with the kerberos package. It may not support Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda [comes with](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) the [kerberos_sspi](https://github.com/may-day/kerberos-sspi) which is "API level equivalent to the kerberos python package but instead of using the MIT krb5 package it uses the windows sspi functionality".

If you have an older version of Anaconda that does not have `kerberos_sspi` installed, you can install it via `conda install -c anaconda kerberos_sspi`