# gcc.exe error while installing kerberos using the Anaconda distribution

Tags: python, windows, gcc, kerberos, anaconda

New to python, trying to install [kerberos](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kerberos). I am trying to use pip install kerberos on windows with the Anaconda 2.7 distribution, but am running into an error with the gcc compiler. I am having the same problem as [someone before me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653958/add-kerberos-from-pypi-to-anaconda-under-windows#new-answer?newreg=4c9e919698334ccd9314896df474344a), with the same output error code. The question went unresolved in the other post. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Duplicate problems are frowned upon but the Stack Overflow community and usually get closed. Maybe you can add a comment to the other question where the person is having the same error?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I tried to comment on the other post, but do not yet have the '50 reputation' required to comment on the post. I am a very new member to Stack Overflow...

Comment: Ok, forgot about the 50 reputation requirement to make a comment.

Comment: I think there is an issue with the kerberos package. It may not support Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I searched for issues with installing kerberos on Windows, and found a solution in a past post (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22269578/4812260). The proposed solution worked for me.